# Не запускается подсистема для линукс после перeустановки винды

Tags: wsl2

Всем привет! Недавно переустанавливал Windows 11 и попытался запустить Ubuntu в wsl 2.
При попытке запуска, терминал выдает ошибку (см.картинку 1). В доп. компонентах уже ставил и убирал галочку и еще раз ставил (флажок подсистема windows для linux). Ничего не помогает. При попытке установки ubuntu и повершеле выдает такую ошибку(см.картинку 2)

[image]

[image]